# Find the upper bound and lower bound of the number of prime numbers less than x

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

In 1962, Rosser in a [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631807) proposed this formula to estimate the number of primes:

$$0.6x/\ln x < \pi(2x)-\pi(x) < 1.4x/\ln x.$$

How can this formula be used to estimate upper bound and the lower bound of the number of 512-bit prime numbers?

Comment: Hint : The numbers with $512$ bits are the numbers from $2^{511}$ to $2^{512}-1$